# how to access the controller of a subfolder of a bundle in Symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

I already had a bundle and a controller inside this bundle, now I added a sub folder in controller to designate the controllers of my API that I created. But now I want to access the controller that is located in the API subfolder. 
I would like to know how to access the controller i.e ApiAdminController.php that is in the sub folder API, through the path in my routing_api.yml ?
Here is an image of the tree of my bundle:

[image: tree of my bundle]

This is my routing_api.yml

**routing_api.yml**

```
doctix_admin_api_parametre:
     path:    /api/admin/parametre
     defaults: { _controller: DoctixAdminBundle:ApiAdmin:getParametre}
```

**My Controller**

```
  class ApiAdminController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/api/admin/parametre")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getParametreAction(Request $request){

    return JsonResponse([

            new Specialite("chirurgie"),
            new Specialite("oncologie"),


    ]);

}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Nowadays it is recommended to avoid some of the mental gymnastics required with the colon notation and just use the fully qualified controller class name and method name.  Doctix\AdminBundle\Controller\API\ApiAdminController:getParametreAction

Comment: Is your `services.yaml` configured to pickup Controllers from the new directory?

Comment: The other thing is that there is no point in using a routing.yaml file as well as annotations.  One or the other but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
doctix_admin_api_parametre:
     path:    /api/admin/parametre
     defaults: { _controller: "DoctixAdminBundle:API\\ApiAdmin:getParametre" }
```